# Vue: Is it an antipattern for a mixin to call a method to be implemented in a component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I'm currently trying to refactor existing components to be DRY, so I'm building a mixin among other things.

However, I find it necessary to call component's specific methods from within the mixin's own methods or lifecycle hooks and, despite it works, it rings somewhat as an antipattern:

**calendarMixin.js**:

```
let calendarMixin = {
  created () {
    this.getCalendar();
  }
};
```

**CalendarOne.vue**

```
export default {
  mixins: [calendarMixin],
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('storeCalendarOne', ['getCalendar'])
  }
};
```

**CalendarTwo.vue**

```
export default {
  mixins: [calendarMixin],
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('storeCalendarTwo', ['getCalendar'])
  }
};
```

Maybe some sort of documentation in the mixin would be appropiate to specify which methods **must** be implemented in the component using the mixin, but it doesn't solve any problems regarding the code like an OOP's interface would.

I was also wondering if TypeScript in Vue would provide a solution to this, like defining strict implementation statements in the mixins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should also add a getCalendar method to the `mixin` so when the getCalendar is not implemented in one of the 2 components, you don't get an error on runtime

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vuex I would structure my code like this:

```
/src
  /mixins
    CalendarMixins.js
  /components
    CalendarOne.vue
```

CalendarMixins.js

```
import {mapActions} from 'vuex'

export default {
  created () {
    this.getCalendar();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getCalendar'])
  }
}
```

CalendarOne.vue

```
import CalendarMixins from '@/mixins/CalendarMixins'
import {mapActions} from 'vuex'

export default {
  mixins: [CalendarMixins],
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('storeCalendarOne')
  }
}
```